# Connect parent entity with existing child entity in database using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 to design and use a database that has a child Table of users which looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

And an Order table that looks like this:

```
    public class Order
{
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ItemCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate{ get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

}
```

In my database, the field representing the User table in Order table is `User_Id`

Now my issue here (which might be a database design issue) is that before Creating a new User and Order in the database, I want to check if the user exists, and if he does, link it to the new order instead of creating a new User. I have a method that Adds new user if the user doesn't exist and returns either the created or the existing user's `Id` field value.

How to Create a new instance of Order that takes the `Id` value instead of `User` object to avoid having duplicate users, or is there a better way to handle this Use Case?

I tried to return the object instead of the UserId, but it saves a new User in the User Table

Comment: You should have the `ICollection<Order> Orders` property in the `User` class.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your problem. But this way should ensure that you don't create another user object, but instead retrieves a user object from db.

```
 public class UserHandler
    {
        //Use dbcontext instead to get a user list
        public List<User> UserList = new List<User>();
        public void handleUserList(int id)
        {
            User oneUser = UserList.FirstOrDefault(n => n.id==id);
            if (oneUser.Equals(null))
            {
                oneUser = new User();
                //Functionality to save the user information
            }
        }
    }
```

Another tip is to use data annotations for properties to make sure they will act the way you want.

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ItemCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate{ get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I have no problem checking if the user existed, or creating a new user. The issue is that whenever I save a new order, it also saves a new user, even if the user existed (I send a user with the id included, but a new one is created anyways)